# Why do we need to specify redirect uri two times while using Oauth2

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I was wondering why we need to specify the redirect uri both in our code and in google developer console when using Oauth2.I was following this tutorial http://www.tothenew.com/blog/grails-way-of-oauth-2-0-to-access-google-apis-part-1/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only redirect URI which really matters is the one which you enter into your Google Developer Console.  This redirect URI is what Google will use to reconnect with your web application after it has either approved or rejected your authorization attempt.

The reason you are *also* specifying this redirect URL in your code is to ensure that your application can correctly recognize the incoming redirect request.

Answer (score 2):

The client may register multiple `redirect_uri`'s with the Authorization Server (i.e. Google) and sending the `redirect_uri` in the request itself is to let the Authorization Sever know on which one of the registered `redirect_uri`'s the client wants to receive the authorization response.

The `redirect_uri` parameter is optional by spec: if there's only one registered, then the `redirect_uri` parameter may be omitted from the request.